# How to use jQuery variable with 'input:checked'

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
var counter = $(buildStep5 'input:checked').length;
```

`buildStep5` is a variable holding the fifth form tag in my HTML document.  I can't get my line of code to work.

I want to get a number for how many checkboxes are currently checked inside of the variable `buildStep5`.

Comment: `$(buildStep5 + ' input:checked').length;`? What is inside `buildStep5`? `#form5` or `.form5` or something?

Comment: Is `buildStep5` a selector or the actual form (node)?

Comment: To explain @putvande comment - you need a space between the `buildStep5` and the `input` - also need a "+" to join them, assuming this is a typo.

Comment: "variable holding tag" - is the variable a string name "id5" or with # "#id5" or the actual tag `$("#id5")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the second parameter of the jQuery selector to restrict the search. This can either be a *reference* to an element, or itself a string *selector*.

```
var buildStep5 = $('#form5');
var counter = $('input:checked',buildStep5).length
```

or

```
var counter = $('input:checked','#form5').length
```

Here's a (slightly contrived) example.

```js
var buildStep5 = $('#form5');
var counter = $("input:checked",buildStep5).length;
alert(counter);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form></form>
<form></form>
<form></form>
<form></form>
<form id="form5">
  <input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" checked><input type="checkbox" checked><input type="checkbox">
</form>
```

Comment: The 2nd argument of the jQuery selector was what I was forgetting.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Or if not working, do

```
var theFrm = buildStep5 + ' input:checked';
$(theFrm).length;
```

Comment: What do you mean _Or if not working_? It IS not working.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.